# Android insert an image from strings.xml file

Tags: android, xml, string

Hi guys I need to use some images inside my book.

My app is using fragments and ViewPager for displaying texts and by changing page it shows new string on same TextView so I can't use ImageView to show Images in some places of book that I want.

The only way I figured out that it may be possible is to define it inside strings file and between texts, but it doesn't work by now. It's one part of my strings file:

```
<string name="textch1"><b>CHAPTER ONE</b>
 \n\n<b>The Boy Who Lived</b>
 <img src="file:///android_asset/1.jpg"/>
 \n\nMr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they       were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be   involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just didn’t hold with such   nonsense.
 \n\nMr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.
</string>
```

my image name is 1.jpg and it's inside assets folder of project's root.

thank you guys

Comment: The other thing that I'm thinking about is that logically it's not possible to show an image inside a TextView so what should I do? Any solutions would be great.

Comment: Yes, you can show an image inside a text view. Actually, you can place an image at bottom, top, right or left of a text in an text view. Use the [TextView.setCompoundDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) API to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use a WebView, which allows you to format the object perfectly using html and also allows to manages the text alignment , wight, font, size etc .

try using a webview and proceed as follows.

```
WebView view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViev);
        String data=new String();


        data="<html><head></head><body><b>CHAPTER ONE</b> \n\n<b>The Boy Who Lived</b><br/> <img src=\"file:///android_asset/photo.jpg\"  height=\"150\" width=\"150\"/><p>Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they       were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be   involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just didn’t hold with such   nonsense.Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.</p></body></html>";

        view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data,"text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

You can use the string data in your strings.xml file. And the image to be loaded is placed in the assets folder of the android porject. Both jpg and png formats will work for image.
You can use the baseUrL and historyURL.

Comment: Thank you I will try this and let you now.

Comment: I want to do it from xml