# Browse the content of a directory in Android

Tags: android, file, directory

Here is the file system of my project. I want to get the names of the text files(untitled 1, untitled 2 ...) in the directory called "folder". And after getting their names I want to read the text in each individual text file. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why not put the files under resources? I think your folder will not packed with you app. You can create a folder in external storage and then place the files there

Comment: The text files must remain unchangeable.

Comment: Then resources. But only your app has control over his folder in external storage. Did you extract the apk and checked if your folder exist?

Comment: I am not aware how to use the external storage. If there is a way to do this can you post it as an answer ? Note that it is essential that the text files remain unchangeable and they are all combined in a separate folder. The  folder is created as soon as the apk is installed

Comment: Sorry but your problem makes no sense for me. All my suggestions can easily googled.

Comment: @rmertins, you mean private internal memory. All apps have at least read access to all extern memory.

Comment: Move the directory 'folder' to the assets directory. Your app can query the assets manager to list the filenames of all the files in 'folder'. You can also read all the text from every file without having to copy the file first.

Answer (score 0):

move your files to assets folder and

```
context.getAssets().open("Untitled 1");
```

or

Place your text file in the /assets directory under the Android project. Use AssetManager class to access it.

```
AssetManager asetmng = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = asetmngm.open("Untitled 1.txt");
```

toget Your file names from res/raw use the following code.

```
Class rw=R.raw.class;
         Field[] fild=rw.getFields();

         for (int i = 0; i < fild.length; i++) {

             System.out.println("File name "+fild[i].getName());
        }
```

to get the resource id from field, use fild[i].getInt(null);

Comment: At first I want to get the names of the text files of the folder. Suppose that you don't know the names in advance

Comment: `file:///android_res/raw/` Sorry but you cannot use such in your app. This doesnot work at all.

Comment: @greenapps It will work if you know the exact file name.

Comment: @greenapps May be you are right, but I think I have used it sometime.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615588/android-insert-an-image-from-strings-xml-file/24619249#24619249

Comment: I just want to show an example. I couldn't recall it, but I have used it once.

Answer (score 0):

Place your text file in the `/assets` directory under the Android project. Use `AssetManager` class to access it.

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
```

Or you can also put the file in the `/res/raw` directory, where the file will be indexed and is accessible by an id in the R file:

`InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);`